# GAE - Sign in to Google crashes Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-signin

Eclipse crashes when I attempt to "Sign in to Google".

Then a dialog pops up with the following message:

`Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:/glassfish4/jdk7/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
javaagent:"C:/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6/lib/agend/appengine-agent.jar"
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
C:/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
C:\Eclipse\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup
C:/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 1954_64
-launcher.library
c:/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm C:/glassfish4/jdk7/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-javaagent:"C:/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar"
-jar C:/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar`

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Cheers!